# how to refresh BeautifulSoup's cache？

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I use BeautifulSoup to modify html files. But I think the modification which I have made cannot write back to BeautifulSoup's cache immediately. For example:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = "<div>some content here</div>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.select("div")
[<div>some content here</div>]

>>> soup.select("div")[0]['class'] = 'test'
>>> soup.select("div")
[<div class="test">some content here</div>]

>>> soup.select(".test")
[]
```

As you can see here, the `soup.select(".test")` shows that nothing have been found. But `soup.select("div")` shows there is exactly a tag which has a class named `test` exists.

I speculate that the cache mechanism causes this problem. Can anyone tell me what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't look an issue with cache.

```
soup.find("div", {"class":"test"})
```

returns `<div class="test">some content here</div>`